# vscode terminal path to sqlite doesn't save

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, path

I set (appended) the path to new install of sqlite3. it didn't work in my vscode terminal afterward, only working in cmd. So, I set it again in vscode as well, assuming that vscode is running a different terminal, requiring its own path variable,,, but when I came back later that day after shutdown and new startup, the path for sqlite3 needed to be added again. it appears as though I will need to add it every time I want to use sqlite3 in my vscode terminal

I'm pretty newb, so I haven't tried much other than setting it again, then trying to look up the keywords on google and the vscode documentation, but so far I haven't found a setting or command to save the path variable permanently.

Comment: well. i set it in system tools, which took me a while before knowing i couldn't just kill the terminal, i had to reboot vscode completely before the terminal in vscode took the new path. still, setx didnt work, even with vscode restart, i only succeded in system menu

Answer (score 0):

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>comma</kbd>
- Search for `terminal integrated shell` + your OS
- Type in the path of sqlite shell (You can use `whereis sqlite3`)

You can also add line `"terminal.integrated.shell.${yourOS}" : "path/to/shell"` to your global `settings.json` file.